# Function to find whether a tree is mono (all the elements are unique) or not?

Tags: c++, unix, recursion, binary-search-tree, binary-search

Im trying to add Total function and isMono functions to this code. Did total already

Need help with function ismono which returns whether a tree is mono (all the elements are unique aka no element appears more than one time) or not. Please

```
#ifndef T_H

#define T_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct tnode {
    int info ;
    int count;
    tnode * right, *left;
};

tnode * insert(int target,tnode * t);
tnode * makenode(int x);
tnode * tsearch(int x,tnode * t);
void inorder(tnode * t);
int height(tnode * t);
int count(tnode * t) ;
int total(tnode * t) ;

#endif

int main() {
int n,c;
tnode * t = NULL, *x;
    while (cin >> n) {t=insert(n,t);cout << n <<' ';}
    cout << endl;
    inorder(t);
    cout << endl;
    c = count(t);
    cout << "count: "<< c  <<endl;
    cout << endl;
    c = height(t);
    cout << "height: "<< c  <<endl;
    cout << endl;
    c=200;
    while (c-->0) if (x = tsearch(c,t)) cout << c << " is on the tree."<<endl;
return 0;
}

#include "t.h"

int count(tnode * t) {
    if (t == NULL) return 0;
    return 1 +  count(t->left) + count (t->right);
}

#include "t.h"

int height(tnode * t) {
    if (t == NULL) return -1;
    return 1 + max(height(t->left) , height (t->right));
}

#include "t.h"

//write out t in order
void inorder(tnode * t) {
    if (t == NULL) return;
    inorder (t->left);//write out lst in order
    cout <<setw(5) << t->info <<setw(5) << t->count<< endl;
    inorder (t->right);//write out rst in order
}

#include "t.h"

tnode * insert(int x, tnode * t) {
tnode * tmp = tsearch(x,t);
if (tmp != NULL) {
    tmp->count++;
    return t;
}
if (t == NULL) return makenode(x);
if ( x < t->info ) {
    t->left = insert(x,t->left);
    return t;
}
t->right = insert(x,t->right);
return t;
}

#include "t.h"

tnode * makenode(int x) {
tnode * t = new tnode;
    t->info =x;
    t->count =1;
    t->right = t->left = NULL;
return t;
}
```

Comment: int compare(tree * t)
{
   if(t == NULL) return true;
   then like compare left and right tree?

Answer (score 1):

## Just traverse the tree!

```
//Gets the value of the node at the leftmost node
int left_most_value(tnode * t) {
    if (t == NULL) return (0); //Something went wrong
    if (t->left == NULL) return(t->info);
    else return(left_most_value(t));
}

//Gets the value of the node at the rightmost node    
int right_most_value(tnode * t) {
    if (t == NULL) return (0); //Something went wrong
    if (t->right == NULL) return(t->info);
    else return(right_most_value(t));
}

//Returns true (1) if node does NOT have duplicate
int node_is_mono(tnode * t) {
    //Ignore leaf nodes
    if (t->left == NULL && t->right == NULL) return 1;

    //Check the left side
    if (t->left != NULL && right_most_value(t->left) == t->info) return(0);

    //Check the right side
    if (t->right != NULL && left_most_value(t->right) == t->info) return(0);

    //This node is mono
    return(1);
}

int tree_is_mono(tnode * t) {
    if (t == NULL) return(1);

    //If one node has a duplicate, then the entire tree is NOT mono 
    if (node_is_mono(t) == 0) return 0;
    else return(tree_is_mono(t->left) && tree_is_mono(t->right));
}
```

---

## Explanation of the algoritm

At every node in the tree, you need to perform the following steps.

1. Find the node's left-most node from the node's children on the right.  If they are equal in value then the tree is **NOT** mono (stop searching and `return false`)
2. Find the node's right-most node from the node's children on the left.  If they are equal in value, then the tree is **NOT** mono (stop searching and `return false`)
3. We found no nodes equal in value, so the tree is mono! `return true`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++, you can simply use a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` to store a list of objects in your tree. Then, you use a tree traversal (inorder, preorder, postorder, etc.) and for every object in the traversal, you do the following:

1. You check whether it is already in the `set`. If it is, then `return false;`.
2. You add the element to the `set`.

Then, when you're done with the traversal, you know that there aren't any duplicates, so simply `return true;`.